# Para que serve 'final' em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estava no Github e deparei-me com uma classe desta maneira:

```
final class Noticia
{
    [...]
}
```

Para que serve esta palavra reservada final?

­Só pode ser utilizada em classes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A palavra chave `final` pode ser usada apenas em classes e métodos basicamente significa que uma classe não pode ter nenhuma filha (herança).

Em métodos significa que as subclasses não podem sobrescrever/modificar esse método.

Exemplo de classe que não pode subclasses:

```
 final class A{
    public function f(){
        echo 'f';
    }
 }

 class b extends a{
    public function x(){
        echo 'x';
    }
 }
```

Retorna:

> Class b may not inherit from final class (A)

Exemplo de método que não pode ser sobrescrito:

```
class A{
    public final function f(){
        echo 'f';
    }
 }

 class b extends a{
    public function f(){
        echo 'minha implementação';
    }
 }
```

Retorna:

> Cannot override final method A::f()

Answer (score 8):

Este comando serve para que a classe não possa ser herdada. Ela deverá ser a classe final de uso.

Exemplo, você cria uma classe chamada `pessoa`, dela você herda e cria `pessoa_fisica` e `pessoa_juridica`, nestas duas finais, você colocaria `final class` para que por exemplo, não seja criado uma classe derivada de `pessoa_fisica` ou `pessoa_juridica`. Se você tentar herdar, receberá um erro.

De acordo com a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.final.php), veja uma definição de classes que receberia um erro:

```
<?php

final class ClasseBase {
   public function teste() {
       echo "Método ClasseBase::teste() chamado\n";
   }

   // Aqui não importa se você especificar a função como Final ou não
   final public function maisTeste() {
       echo "Método ClasseBase::maisTeste() chamado\n";
   }
}

class ClasseFilha extends ClasseBase {
}
// Resulta em erro Fatal: A classe ClasseFilha não pode herdar de uma classe Final (ClasseBase)

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

É uma forma de dizer que esta classe não pode ser herdada, o que costuma ser uma boa ideia. Desenvolver classes preparadas para serem herdadas é muito mais difícil, a manutenção seguinte se torna um fardo. Acho até que o padrão deveria ser a classe não *herdável*.

Pode ser usado em método também dizendo que ele não pode ser sobrescrito quando em classes herdáveis. O que também deveria ser o padrão, embora um dos motivos que é a performance não faz diferença em PHP.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php). Estes códigos dão erro:

```
class BaseClass {
   public function test() {
       echo "BaseClass::test() called\n";
   }

   final public function moreTesting() {
       echo "BaseClass::moreTesting() called\n";
   }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
   public function moreTesting() {
       echo "ChildClass::moreTesting() called\n";
   }
}


final class BaseClass {
   public function test() {
       echo "BaseClass::test() called\n";
   }

   // Here it doesn't matter if you specify the function as final or not
   final public function moreTesting() {
       echo "BaseClass::moreTesting() called\n";
   }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Final.php).